# Barplot comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I would like to draw a barplot graph that would compare the evolution of 2 variables of revenues on a monthly time-axis (12 months of invoices).

I wanted to use sns.barplot, but can't use "hue" (cause the 2 variables aren't subcategories?). Is there another way, as simple as with hue? Can I "create" a hue?

Here is a small sample of my data:

(I did transform my table into a pivot table)

`[In]`

```
data_pivot['Revenue-Small-Seller-in'] = data_pivot["Small-Seller"] + data_pivot["Best-Seller"] + data_pivot["Medium-Seller"]
data_pivot['Revenue-Not-Small-Seller-in'] = data_pivot["Best-Seller"] + data_pivot["Medium-Seller"]
data_pivot
```

`[Out]`

```
InvoiceNo   Month   Year    Revenue-Small-Seller-in Revenue-Not-Small-Seller-in
 536365       12    2010             139.12                   139.12
 536366       12    2010              22.20                    11.10
 536367       12    2010             278.73                   246.93
```

([sorry for the ugly presentation of my data, see the picture to see the complete table (as there are multiple columns))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZP0S.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
render_df = data_pivot[data_pivot.columns[-2:]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
render_df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or `sns` style like you requested

```
render_df = data_pivot[data_pivot.columns[-2:]].stack().reset_index()
sns.barplot('level_0', 0, hue='level_1',
            render_df)
```

here `render_df` after `stack()` is:

```
+---+---------+-----------------------------+--------+
|   | level_0 |           level_1           |   0    |
+---+---------+-----------------------------+--------+
| 0 |       0 | Revenue-Small-Seller-in     | 139.12 |
| 1 |       0 | Revenue-Not-Small-Seller-in | 139.12 |
| 2 |       1 | Revenue-Small-Seller-in     | 22.20  |
| 3 |       1 | Revenue-Not-Small-Seller-in | 11.10  |
| 4 |       2 | Revenue-Small-Seller-in     | 278.73 |
| 5 |       2 | Revenue-Not-Small-Seller-in | 246.93 |
+---+---------+-----------------------------+--------+
```

and output:

[image]

Comment: I don't really get the use of the "level"s. Plus, I have more than those 5 columns I showed (by simplicity, but maybe I should have typed the complete table). I just added a picture of the complete pivot table (which I know isn't the easier, sorry).

Comment: @LolaVanpump They are results of `reset_index` on a double index. See the edit, hope it helps.